# Error al llamar generic handlers (ashx) c# con JavaScript getXMLObject

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, http

tengo un **generic handlers** que pienso utilizar para comprobar la conexión de base de datos desde mi pagina web, el mismo es llamado por un archivo **JS** el cual usa **XMLHttpRequest** para realizar la petición al servidor **IIS local** y retornar un objeto que se mostrara en el ASPX, sin embargo al realizar la petición el navegador recibe un **request response 404** y al buscar el la url con el objeto getXMLObject(); solo arroja **status http 302 found**

Este es mi handler:

```
public class folderAccess : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        ManageForm(context);
    }

    public void ManageForm(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write("<html><body><form>");

        context.Response.Write("<h2>Hello there. What's cool about .NET?</h2>");
        context.Response.Write("<select name='Feature'>");
        context.Response.Write("<option> Strong typing</option>");
        context.Response.Write("<option> Managed code</option>");
        context.Response.Write("<option> Language agnosticism</option>");
        context.Response.Write("<option> Better security model</option>");
        context.Response.Write("<option> Threading and async delegates</option>");
        context.Response.Write("<option> XCOPY deployment</option>");
        context.Response.Write("<option> Reasonable HTTP handling framework</option>");
        context.Response.Write("</select>");
        context.Response.Write("</br>");
        context.Response.Write("<input type=submit name='Lookup' value='Lookup'></input>");
        context.Response.Write("</br>");

        context.Response.Write("</form></body></html>");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

este es el javascript que lo llama

```
function callAjaxPost(url, params, callBack) {
var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        callBackAjax(xmlhttp, null, callBack);
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

}

este es la función que esta en el ASPX que llama al archivo JS

```
function browseAccess(path) {
    var sid = document.getElementById("sessionid").value;
    var div = document.getElementById("divPermisos");
    wait();
    callAjaxPost("(S(" + sid + "))/testProyect/folderAccess.ashx", "path=" + path + "&domain=" + _$("SET.domain").value, listFolder);
}

function listFolder(val) {
    val = "<div style='width:680px;height:350px;overflow:auto'>" + val + "</div>";
    showMsg(val, "<%=M0074%>", 700, true);
}
```

respuesta del navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo no usaria in post sino un get, en el siguiente link, hay un buen ejemplo de como hacerlo. http://www.devcurry.com/2010/11/call-aspnet-handler-ashx-using.html Saludos,